# Fill ComboBox with Access DB data

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C# to create a windows form with a combobox that should contain employees initials. I have spent the last few days searching through every solution I can find and I still can not get my combobox to populate.

This is what I've got as of now:

```
public static void FillComboBox(string Query, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox LoggedByBox)
{
    using (var CONN = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Documents\\Service Request Application\\bin\\Debug\\servicereq1.mdb"))
    {
        CONN.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, CONN);
            OleDbDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(myReader);
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

            return;
        }
        LoggedByBox.DataSource = dt;
        LoggedByBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        LoggedByBox.DisplayMember = "Initials";
    }
}
```

Then I call it when the form loads

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillComboBox("select ID, Initials from [Fixers and Testers]", LoggedByBox);
}
```

When I run the program, the combobox is still blank. I'm positive that my column names and table names are correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the debugger to see what values are in your dt.  If it's empty, you are probably looking at the wrong database.

Comment: It says the name dt does not exist in the current context...how do I fix that @LarsTech

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `LoggedByBox.DataSource = dt;` and examine the values of the Rows collection of dt when the code stops at that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got my ComboBox filled and I wanted to share what I changed for anyone else who stumbles across this question in their searches. After spending a bit more time searching through other questions and MSDN, I was able to come up with this.

```
    private void LoadComboLogged()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",@"\\prod\ServiceRequests");

        string strCon = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\servicereq1.mdb";

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string strSql = "SELECT Initials FROM [Fixers and Testers] WHERE [Status] ='C'";
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                loggedByComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                loggedByComboBox.DisplayMember = "Initials";
                loggedByComboBox.ValueMember = "Initials";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I also found that I needed to call

```
    LoadComboLogged();
```

when I initialized my form. Without that line, the ComboBox would only show a blank dropdown list. Hope this helps someone else who runs into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Passing control to static method causing this issue. Instead of passing control to the method make that method returns the table and within the load method load the control.

Comment: `Passing control to static method causing this issue.` Do you have that documented somewhere?  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RUSH-PC\\RUSH;Initial Catalog=Att;Integrated Security=True");

            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from userinfo", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 1);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "name";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;    
            con.Close();
```

This may help you...
Good luck...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to query and return a list of strings. Perhaps it may be less efficient, but it's what I used in a recent project of mine. Here's an example that would reside in a method, possibly called GetInitialsFromDatabase():

```
using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    conn.Open();
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Initials FROM [Fixers and Testers]  WHERE [Status] ='C'";
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // initials is a List<String> previously defined (Assuming strings)
            initials.Add(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

And then return the initials List, and then in your GUI you could say:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = returnedList;
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```